# How to get subkeys as a root in mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have collection look like below

```
    { 
    "_id" : "62a83686c379ed7f4a438532", 
    "message" : "LOGIN_FAILED", 
    "context" : {
        "reason" : "errors.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", 
        "username" : "ryryrtyrty", 
        "skin" : "example.com", 
        "country" : "India", 
        "state" : "02", 
        "device" : "Desktop", 
        "os" : "Linux", 
        "browser" : "Chrome", 
        "datetime" : "2022-06-14"
    }, 
    "level" : 200.0, 
    "level_name" : "INFO", 
    "channel" : "default", 
    "datetime" : "2022-06-14T07:19:34.220+0000", 
    "extra" : [

    ], 
    "timestamp" : "2022-06-14 07:19:34.220998"
  }
```

what i want i am using mongodb with Laravel 9, i want to fetch data through query which should output as below

```
   {
    "reason" : "errors.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", 
    "username" : "ryryrtyrty", 
    "skin" : "OjoTest.nl", 
    "country" : "CY", 
    "state" : "02", 
    "device" : "Desktop", 
    "os" : "Linux", 
    "browser" : "Chrome", 
    "datetime" : "2022-06-14"
}
```

I am trying to run below query

```
LoginLog::project(['context.os'=>1, 'context.browser'=>1])->orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')->get();
```

but it still gives me output as below

```
"context" : {
        "reason" : "errors.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE", 
        "username" : "ryryrtyrty", 
        "skin" : "example.com", 
        "country" : "India", 
        "state" : "02", 
        "device" : "Desktop", 
        "os" : "Linux", 
        "browser" : "Chrome", 
        "datetime" : "2022-06-14"
    }
```

Please let me know what should i change to get desired output

Answer (score 1):

Use `$replaceRoot`. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$context"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O2KjEjxdJEz)